# How to use time value of benchmark

Tags: go, benchmarking

I have written a benchmark for my chess engine in Go:

```
func BenchmarkStartpos(b *testing.B) {
    board := ParseFen(startpos)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Perft(&board, 5)
    }
}
```

I see this output when it runs:

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkStartpos-4           10     108737398 ns/op
PASS
ok      _/Users/dylhunn/Documents/go-chess  1.215s
```

I want to use the time per execution (in this case, `108737398 ns/op`) to compute another value, and also print it as a result of the benchmark. Specifically, I want to output *nodes per second*, which is given as the result of the `Perft` call divided by the time per call.

How can I access the time the benchmark took to execute, so I can print my own derived results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the [`testing.Benchmark()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark) function to manually measure / benchmark "benchmark" functions (that have the signature of `func(*testing.B)`), and you get the result as a value of [`testing.BenchmarkResult`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#BenchmarkResult), which is a struct with all the details you need:

```
type BenchmarkResult struct {
    N         int           // The number of iterations.
    T         time.Duration // The total time taken.
    Bytes     int64         // Bytes processed in one iteration.
    MemAllocs uint64        // The total number of memory allocations.
    MemBytes  uint64        // The total number of bytes allocated.
}
```

The time per execution is returned by the [`BenchmarkResult.NsPerOp()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#BenchmarkResult.NsPerOp) method, you can do whatever you want to with that.

See this simple example:

```
func main() {
    res := testing.Benchmark(BenchmarkSleep)
    fmt.Println(res)
    fmt.Println("Ns per op:", res.NsPerOp())
    fmt.Println("Time per op:", time.Duration(res.NsPerOp()))
}

func BenchmarkSleep(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 12)
    }
}
```

Output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0Rf_y1vNUp)):

```
     100      12000000 ns/op
Ns per op: 12000000
Time per op: 12ms
```

Comment: Since this solution contains a `main()` function, it must be placed in a "main" package, right? My project is a library, so there is no main package, and adding one to the repo would cause difficulties with people acquiring it via `go get`. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @dylhunn I included a link to the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0Rf_y1vNUp) where you can try it. Having a `main()` function is so just you can try it out of the box. You can use the code inside the `main()` function _everywhere_, obviously including non-`main` functions too, also including test packages.

Comment: @ixza Ah, I understand. Thanks for the help!